# The "cannot be added because it does not have a primary key" bug in NetBeans

Tags: mysql, jsp, netbeans

I try to create a Entity Class from my MySQL Database. The wizard in Netbeans give me the error message "cannot be added because it does not have a primary key". But i got a primary key in my table. It seems to be a bug that others have encountered in this forum:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167389

I have tried the suggestions in the thread but have not gotten it to work. what am I missing? Can I force Netbeans to import the Entity class?

Im using NetBeans 7.3

Here is my table:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estelle`.`FrasVal` (
`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Varde` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL ,
`Kommentar` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL ,
`RegistreratDatum` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`FrasFragaSvarAlternativ_ID` INT(11) NULL ,
`Anvandare_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`Patient_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`FrasFraga_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FrasVal_FrasFragaSvarAlternativ1_idx` (`FrasFragaSvarAlternativ_ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FrasVal_Anvandare1_idx` (`Anvandare_ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FrasVal_Patient1_idx` (`Patient_ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FrasVal_FrasFraga1_idx` (`FrasFraga_ID` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FrasVal_FrasFragaSvarAlternativ1`
FOREIGN KEY (`FrasFragaSvarAlternativ_ID` )
REFERENCES `estelle`.`FrasFragaSvarAlternativ` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FrasVal_Anvandare1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Anvandare_ID` )
REFERENCES `estelle`.`Anvandare` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FrasVal_Patient1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Patient_ID` )
REFERENCES `estelle`.`Patient` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FrasVal_FrasFraga1`
FOREIGN KEY (`FrasFraga_ID` )
REFERENCES `estelle`.`FrasFraga` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried the suggestions in the thread but have not gotten it to work.

Are you sure? The code sample you have posted don't show that. If necessary, update your question to reflect the actual state of your problem.

---

According to [the link you provided](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167389#c4), a possible (?) workaround would be to spell you table all lowercase:

> "Something that gave me a hard time is that for some funky reason the
>   table names must be all in lower case. If tables names are in mixed
>   case the relationships will not be discovered during the reverse
>   engineering process. During my experimentation I discovered that the
>   Middlegen docs give a warning about this, so I am guessing that the
>   Eclipse DALI plugin uses Middlegen under the covers. The MySQL engine
>   should also be INNODB."

And https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167389#c11

> The problem will happen if you have foreign keys where upper case and
>   lower case table names don't match the referenced table's definition.

---

I would suggest (1) to use all lowercase table names and (2) ensure that table references are spelled the same on foreign key constraints.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estelle`.`frasval` (
--                                     ^^^^^^^
 ...

REFERENCES `estelle`.`frasfragasvaralternativ` (`ID` )
--                    ^   ^    ^   ^
```

You should probably be able to use underscore `_` in your table name as well (definitively make things more readable!). Please post your conclusions if you have time to made some experiments!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Hmm this is a scary error . I redid all the tables that have a one to one relationship to this table with one to many relationship and got it to work. It seems that this error message is generally too many errors in the database

Answer (score 0):

When I got the error I removed the foreign keys, added them again, restarted the mysql connection and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It is because the first character on the name of your field "ID" is Uppercase. Try with 'id'. I know, sounds fool but this worked for me.